# Does GitHub has cross-referencing of function locations in source code?

Tags: github, version-control

When I saw cross-referencing, I do not mean things like this,

https://help.github.com/articles/autolinked-references-and-urls/#commit-shas

I mean like here,

http://phpcrossref.com/xref/drupal/includes/bootstrap.inc.html

for pages such as,

https://github.com/drupal/drupal/blob/1e04b3623fe8a9db8a1d86368b09b5bbadb33e78/core/modules/user/src/Tests/UserPermissionsTest.php

where you can click the function name and show where all it occurs.  I could not find where this could be done in GitHub.

Edit:  I probably gave a poor example with Drupal, as they have this on their site, but I was hoping it would be something universal I could use for any GitHub code.

Edit:  I don't believe you can do this, so I am simply highlighting the code and dragging it to the search for "This Repository."

Comment: Sure: click the line numbers on any Github code view and you'll get a link like this: https://github.com/drupal/drupal/blob/1e04b3623fe8a9db8a1d86368b09b5bbadb33e78/core/modules/user/src/Tests/UserPermissionsTest.php#L31-L40

Comment: @ceejayoz I'm not following.  It only highlights that line.

Comment: Hold shift when you click the second one.

Comment: I do not think I have asked correctly.  It is only showing me the line I click.  If I use shift it highlights multiple lines.  I do not see where I can click a function and it show me all occurrences of that function in the source.

Comment: No, github is not an IDE.